# Best way to get notification to rootViewController

Tags: ios

I am looking for some advice as to the best way to handle this situation:

In my appDelegate I call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

However, I need to wait for a device token to be returned before my app can continue, so I was wondering what the best place to wait for this before continuing?  Currently my `viewDidLoad` gets called, but I sometimes have failures because the device token did not come back yet.

I was thinking that I could move my code from `viewDidLoad` to `myViewDidLoad` and was hoping I could wait for a notification that would happen once I receive the device token and then call `myViewDidLoad`.

But, I am not sure where to set the notification.  I know this is a basic question, but I am still learning iOS.

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, and due to the lack of any helpful posts, I corrected my issue by creating a member variable in my app delegate that is the type of myViewController.  Then in viewDidLoad of myViewController, I set it to self.  Later after I receive the deviceToken, I can use the member variable to call a method of my view controller which then runs the methods that require the token.  I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it does solve the problem for now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't wait. Never, never wait.

When dealing with asynchronous stuff like networking (as here), you must write your app in such a way that it can proceed in *some* way even if the networking hasn't happened yet. It's that simple.

Your second impulse is much more correct. When you get the remote notification in the app delegate (I'm assuming), the app delegate can talk to the view controller in question and give it the new info and tell it to update itself (and the view controller can then update the view to display whatever needs displaying at that point).

Since you know you're going to need to do this, you need to set up "lines of sight" communication in advance. You have all the pieces of the puzzle in your hands in the app delegate, so you can arrange to hang on to a reference to that view controller, for when you'll need it later.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  I was thinking I could NSNotification and then add an observer that would call myViewDidLoad and hide my splash screen and so on

Comment: You can but don't. NSNotification is a last resort. You have the ability to construct a direct "line of sight" here. Use that.

Comment: Also don't use a splash screen. What if the remote notification _never_ arrives? What if there is no network? Anything can happen. Be wise. Don't freeze the user into an impossible situation that depends upon chance. Revise your architecture.

Comment: ok, so how do I get a reference to my UIViewController in appDelegate?  As you can see, I am a bit confused.  I have been reading and struggling with this a lot so excuse my dumb questions.

Comment: I don't know because I don't what you're doing. But you've apparently got a navigation controller. Is your view controller its root view controller? Then the problem is already solved.

Comment: Yes, I do have a fallback for that and can direct the user down another path if I do not have the DeviceToken.

Comment: LOL, ok, maybe I am over thinking the issue. If you look at my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, can I cast my 'self.navigationController) to my type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54654/discussion-between-lilmoke-and-matt).

Comment: I've written you a whole book about this kind of stuff. Here's the chapter on how to think about visibility of one instance to another. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_instance_visibility But if you believe that casting changes anything, you need to do a lot more learning about the basic language you're using before you go any further (which other chapters of my discussion also help you with).

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment to my question with my solution. Not ideal, but it works for now.